# comparison operators for messages

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

do I have to provide them myself:

```
namespace std_msgs {
bool operator== (const Header &h1, const Header &h2)
{
  return h1.frame_id==h2.frame_id && h1.stamp==h2.stamp && h1.seq==h2.seq;
}
}

namespace geometry_msgs {
bool operator== (const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
  return p1.x==p2.x && p1.y==p2.y && p1.z==p2.z;
}
bool operator== (const Quaternion &q1, const Quaternion &q2)
{
  return q1.x==q2.x && q1.y==q2.y && q1.z==q2.z && q1.w==q2.w;
}
bool operator== (const Pose &p1, const Pose &p2)
{
  return p1.position==p2.position && p1.orientation==p2.orientation;
}
}
```

etc...

that's seems dumb. I checked the generated header files and no comparison operator is provided. The default constructor initializes things to 0, there is a serialization mechanism, etc. but not comparison operator. Am I missing a point? Is there a good reason to not provide these operators?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193604/comparison-operators-for-messages/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your example is actually quite well chosen: What does it mean for some poses to be equal? The only auto-generated way would be this one, e.g. comparing floats for equality. Is 3.00000001 really different from 3.0000002?

One could argue that float equality would be at least something, but in my opinion this might lead to people accidentally using that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3